# Oracle Triggers not showing in DBA_SOURCE

Tags: oracle, triggers

In our application, only about 25% of the database triggers show up in `DBA_SOURCE`.  I know I can force the others to show up if I make an actual modification (like adding and removing a space) and then recompile the trigger, but I've got about 400 triggers to modify (it's rather a big application).  Just recompiling the triggers with `alter trigger <triggername> compile;` didn't accomplish anything.

Without the triggers being in DBA_SOURCE, we can't do text searches on the trigger code.

Is there some simpler way to accomplish this?  And is there some way to prevent the problem in the future?

We're on Oracle 10.2.0.5.0.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that this is in our development environment, so whatever I do won't mess up production.

Comment: Are the triggers in source control, or are they just in the database? If there are in source control (where they should be) then you should be able to do text searches on the files the triggers are stored in. I admit it is often easier to search the database, but key point is that the database should not be the 'master copy' of code, even on dev - I learned that lesson many years ago the hard way when the wrong dev database was dropped by mistake!

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not in any source control, just in the database. Wish I could convince the rest of the team otherwise, but that's the way it is (I've been here 7 years, and I'm still the newbie here). Maybe I can use this as a push to do that!

Comment: Unfortunately on project after project I have seen, your situation is repeated over and over! At least you seem to accept it is not ideal. Inspired by this, I have been working on a build tool to help teams manage code in the database better. If you are interested have a look at http://dbgeni.com 

On the triggers, I have always found the trigger source in all_source any time I have gone looking for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue. It's a migration issue from older versions of Oracle.

Triggers were not included in DBA_SOURCE in an earlier version (8?, 9i?) and did not get added to DBA_SOURCE when migrating to newer versions. A recompile did not put them into DBA_SOURCE. But if you drop and recreate the triggers, they will be included in DBA_SOURCE.

So my guess is you have some old triggers and have migrated the database in place to newer versions.

Comment: I think you probably hit the nail on the head with this, Jim.  The database has been around for more than 10 years, and it has been upgraded from 9i since I've been here.  I do not know what version it was originally.  Do you know if upgrading to 11g solves this problem?  We're scheduled to do that upgrade sometime next year (early next year, I think).

Comment: I never checked after we moved to 11g, mostly because I think we'd already reloaded all triggers. And I don't have rights to do something like "select * from dba_triggers t where not exists (select 1 from dba_source s where S.TYPE = 'TRIGGER' and s.name = t.trigger_name);" Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  I accepted your answer, not because you answered my question directly, but because you explained the problem.  Nobody else answered the question, either.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can find the source in all_triggers. Unfortunately, the data is in a LONG variable (Oracle example of do as I say, not as I do). So, the easiest thing would be to create a scratch table to use, populate it with the data converted to CLOB, and then search:

```
CREATE TABLE tr (trigger_name VARCHAR2(32), trigger_body CLOB);

INSERT INTO tr 
 (SELECT trigger_name, TO_LOB(trigger_body)
    FROM all_triggers
   WHERE owner = 'xxx');

SELECT trigger_name
  FROM tr
 WHERE trigger_body LIKE '%something%';
```

I'm not sure why the dba_source view is only sparsely populated for triggers. It's that way on my 10.2.0.4 database as well.

EDIT:

Here is a short script you can use to recreate all your triggers, at which point they should all be in dba_source:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_sql (sql1 CLOB, sql2 CLOB);

INSERT INTO temp_sql (sql1, sql2) (
SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER '||
       DESCRIPTION||' '||CASE WHEN when_clause IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'WHEN('||when_clause||')' END sql1,
       to_lob(trigger_body) sql2
  FROM all_triggers
 WHERE table_owner = 'theowner');

DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(32760); 

BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT sql1||' '||sql2 S FROM temp_sql) LOOP
    v_sql := R.s;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: That's OK as a workaround, but then everybody on the whole development team would have to remember to add new or modified triggers to that table whenever they worked on them.

Comment: Or you could simply recreate the data when you needed to search it. In the scheme of things 400 triggers isn't all that much data. In fact, make it a global temporary table and build it each time you need to search.

Comment: You could also query dba_objects to determine when the last DDL was performed on the trigger to know if you needed to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Who owns the triggers?

and, of course, you tried

select owner, object_name
from all_objects
where object_type = 'TRIGGER'
and owner in ('schema1','schema2')

Comment: The triggers are all in the same schema, which also has all of the tables, stored procedures/functions/packages, etc. I can log in to that schema directly, so that's not a problem.  And if a solution requires DBA privileges, our DBA is in the next row of cubicles over from me.